# How to change Month name in Bootstrap Datepicker calendar?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker in my code but the calendar which appears have months like "March","July" etc. Is there any wayto change months full name to "MAR","JUL".
Thanks in advance
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUbUU.jpg)
In this I want August to be AUG

Answer (score 3):

Translate to whatever you want:

> ...simply add a key to $.fn.datepicker.dates,
>   before calling .datepicker() [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html#i18n)

```
$.fn.datepicker.dates['en'] = {
    days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    today: "Today",
    clear: "Clear",
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    titleFormat: "MM yyyy", /* Leverages same syntax as 'format' */
    weekStart: 0
};
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html

change language:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: "pt-BR"
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the datepicker.js?

Comment: You don't have to change datepicker.js file, these are options, just enter this code before using  `$('.datepicker').datepicker({});`

Comment: @lukas-well I dont want to change language, What I want is use monthsShort instead of full names, currently on the top of calendar its coming January I want it to be JAN

Comment: @Frank i don't see such option available, that's why suggested to use this work around to just use translation to change visible values to whatever needed. You can use emoji too! ^^

Comment: can you tell me how to use this option -dayViewHeaderFormat. I think this will help

Comment: can't see such option, are we talking about same plugin? http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Comment: see this link :https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format

Comment: @Frank oh ok, then try using `MMM` value, while this is short name for month at momentjs

Comment: @Frank cheers, would love if you would accept and upvote my answer and comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated in the comments that you are using eonasdan datetimepicker, you can simply use [`dayViewHeaderFormat`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#dayviewheaderformat) option.

Here a working example.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'L',
  dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMM YYYY'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```